# display date as datetime input would

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, datetime

My problem is this: chromes datetime-local is displayed the way my OS is configured (currently dd/mm/yyyy hh:ss) (24h clock) (en-US)

The best way I have came up with to display the date the same way. Was to make an input with readonly and no borders but that's not optimal. i need to have it in a variable (string) and be able to save it and perhaps send a email with the same format (just a example)

The secound best thing was to use `Date.toLocalString();` but it's still not the same as the system or input format

From what i understand and found out

- `Date.toLocalString` is based on geolocation
- `input[datetime-local]` is based on system.
- the system format is a bit of impossible to get.

i don't wish to change the date format/mask of the input (cuz that would not follow the clients wishes)
but i would considering setting the input format/mask to the same format as toLocalString to get the same behavior if that is even possible???

---

[image]

http://plnkr.co/edit/nAfgdkPrFqjk6pyBjs8K?p=preview

---

but now when we have `datetime-local` is there no way we can get the system format from the input field?

Answer (score 1):

(Since this is apparently a Google Chrome question, this answers the question in the same context)

Chrome (and latest versions of other browsers) has an internationalization JavaScript API.
It lets you format numbers and dates and compare strings according to the current (or any supported) locale.

Using [`Intl.DateTimeFormatter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat), you can format the date you get from the input (`new Date(dateInputElement.valueAsNumber)` will give you the raw date object) -

```
var formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat();
console.log(formatter.format(new Date(dateInputElement.valueAsNumber)));
```

You can configure the `DateTimeFormatter` using an options object when you construct it -

```
var formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat((new Intl.DateTimeFormat).resolvedOptions().locale,{year: "numeric", month: "numeric", day: "numeric", hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric", second: "numeric"});
console.log(formatter.format(new Date(dateInputElement.valueAsNumber)));
```

Comment: Hmm, looks promising. I tried it out a bit on my computer and it works. its a little bit harder to tell if it is working as expected. Will see if it solves my problem @ my work (it has different (mixed) settings) if so i will mark you answer as accepted :)

Comment: unfortunately did didn't work. i tried to get the same format as the display value without knowing it in advance. This is only a way to create a interpolate function

Comment: I would recommend asking this as a joined post between blink-dev and v8-users. I am sure they will have a more definite answer (assuming someone answers...).
blink-dev - https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/forum/blink-dev‎
v8-users - https://groups.google.com/d/forum/v8-users

To simulate a joined post, you have to join the groups and send your post using e-mail (meaning, not using the Google Groups interface) and put both of the e-mail addresses of the groups as the recipients.